# -[NSError retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nserror, nszombie, uimanageddocument

With Zombies enabled, I'm getting the error in the title (message sent to deallocated instance of NSError) on the following saveToURL call:

```
[aDocument saveToURL:aDocument.fileURL
forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting
completionHandler:^(BOOL success) { ...
```

Stack trace looks like the following:

[image]

aDocument is an instance of a subclass of UIManagedDocument. I have concurrency debug on and I've looked to see if I have any threading conflicts, haven't been able to find any yet. How can I debug this?

EDIT: Also tried the following code with the same crash occurring

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [aDocument saveToURL:aDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf documentSaved:aDocument forRestoredAssessment:patientAssessment];
            });
        }
    }];
```

EDIT: bounty added

Comment: What are you doing inside the completionHandler?

Comment: This method is called...
            [self documentSaved:aDocument forRestoredAssessment:patientAssessment]; which does a huge bunch of stuff.

Comment: In general it's not safe to touch ANYTHING in UIKit or directly related to UIKit from any thread that is not the main queue. I would in fact assume that's the core of the issue.

Comment: Is `aDocument` a local variable or a property?

Comment: @Sulthan local variable (method parameter)

Comment: your error seems to be that aDocument (or whatever is holding your aDocument) has already been deallocated. performing on background thread?

Comment: @BradThomas I noticed this line in the UIDocument documentation: `Instead, in this case, the error is available to your app in the handleError:userInteractionPermitted: method and in the UIDocumentStateChangedNotification notification.` here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocument/1619978-contentsfortype?language=objc. Maybe if you listen for this notification you could potentially figure out whats going on with the NSError.

Comment: Thanks @Prientus, I think I figured this out already though, see the answer I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out what was causing this, since I made the following change and then the error went away. The error was tricky to resolve though since it did not directly point to this being the cause.

I was using UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting but I discovered that sometimes the file had already been deleted by another process.

So to fix the issue I tested for file existence and then used either UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting or UIDocumentSaveForCreating based on that.

Comment: Could you suggest a code for checking the file existence?

Comment: @GregoryWilsonPullyattu I'm sorry, I no longer have access to the source code for this project, and its been 3 years since I wrote ObjC, so I would have to google the answer just as you would

Answer (score 2):

We have discovered that this zombie occurs when the parent context has a merge conflict.  If you override `[UIManagedDocument writeContents:toURL:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error]` method in your subclass, access the parent context with:`NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(NSDictionary *)contents objectForKey:@"parentContext"];`.  Save the parent context if changes exist using the standard code as below.  If the conflict is resolved by either setting a merge policy or reset the context then the zombie will not occur.

```
- (BOOL)writeContents:(id)contents
                toURL:(NSURL *)url
     forSaveOperation:(UIDocumentSaveOperation)saveOperation
  originalContentsURL:(NSURL *)originalContentsURL
                error:(NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing *)outError {

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext.parentContext;

    if (context.hasChanges) {
        [context performBlockAndWait:^{

            NSError *saveError = nil;
            if (![context save:&saveError]) {
                NSLog(@"Document Writing: error saving context %@", saveError);
                [context reset];
            }
        }];
    }
    return [super writeContents:contents
                          toURL:url
               forSaveOperation:saveOperation
            originalContentsURL:originalContentsURL
                          error:outError];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the object that calls the completion block code may not be around at that time, so you need some way to keep that alive.

Try this code:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakSelf documentSaved:aDocument forRestoredAssessment:patientAssessment]; 
});
```

Let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: I tried your solution. I get the same error. I really don't think it's crashing inside the block. I suspect it might have something to do with trying to save when another thread might be trying to do the same.

Comment: @BradThomas Is aDocument a local variable in the function/method or some class variable?

Comment: aDocument is a parameter passed in to the method

Comment: @BradThomas Does it have a valid value inside the completion block?

Comment: Yes it appears to. But when it crashes, it's not even getting into the completion block. It crashes on the aDocument saveToURL call